# Mouse Hover Bringing Temp Horizontal Scrollbar In jQuery SlideShow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I am seeing. Please look into the picture below and you will see a horizontal scrollbar beneath the slideshow.

[image: Horizontal scrollbar on jQuery slideshow]

And here's the script on HTML page:

```
<div class="fitimage">
   <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="img/copywrtng.jpg" class="headerimage" alt="copywriting"      />
      <img src="img/copywrtng1.jpg" class="headerimage" alt="copywriting" />
      <img src="img/copywrtng2.jpg" class="headerimage" alt="copywriting" />
   </div>
</div>
```

And here's what I have on CSS:

```
div.fitimage {
    width:100%;
    height:93vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imgcontainer {
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
img.headerimage {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
  /*max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;*/
    height:93vh;
}
```

A few things that I cannot understand:

*1. It happens only on mouse hover.*

*2. It happens only for a few seconds and then it disappears, and reappears again.*

*3. It doesn't happen when I see the local web page. It happens only when I uploaded it on a server.*

I tried to figure out if the overflow is turning visible, as soon as the mouse is hovering over it. But what I saw is, a white space is being widened on the right which is rendering the horizontal scroll bar. But the width of the website  is still 100%, and whole website is shifting left with white space on the right. And the slideshow block (the website block) is automatically moving right. The white space is being narrowed again and the whole thing fitting into 100% width.

Just don't understand what's changing when it's loaded on server. Is it some predetermined browser style? Or is it a jQuery glitch?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: create some demo like js fiddle

Comment: yes a demo would be helpfull

Comment: can you paste link here of the website ?

Comment: this is the working link http://www.copyewriting.com/NewHomePage/
checked on IE 11 and Chrome 57, can not recreate the issue. whats the browser you are using?

Comment: [copyewriting.com/NewHomePage](copyewriting.com/NewHomePage)...it's actually a website. And it's already working fine in my JSBin and my PC files. Just don't understand what is happening as I loaded it on the server.

Comment: I don't find any horizontal spacebar on the bootom of the page its working fine. screen size 1920px by 1080px. on this URL: copyewriting.com/NewHomePage/ Its working fine on all browser see the page again

Comment: the issue is on IE, not on chrome

Comment: @Sangrai Just get your mouse on top of the slideshow. It happens only on mouse hover. Not even on the text or the button. The picture itself.

Comment: @julekgwa, I am seeing this on Firefox. :-(

Comment: @Samc I mouse hovered the screen but don't have any scroll bar...

Comment: @Sangrai, Which browser are you using? Did you hover over the picture itself? Not on text or the button.

Comment: There's nothing on my firefox and chrome, maybe the problem is screen size.

Comment: @Samc whats your browser? for me there is no horizontal bar for IE 11 and Chrome 57

Comment: I have seen on all the browser i.e mozila, chrome, Safari, IE etc.

Comment: appears to be working fine on my computer

Comment: I have also checked in responsive view its working fine.. remove all the history from the browser and see gain...

Comment: @Sangrai, are you hovering over the picture? Please confirm. Because as soon as I hover over the slideshow (the picture)...not the button or the text...it's showing the scrollbar, both in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Okay, let me try again. Letting you guys know.

Comment: Hi, I checked it in Chrome. And yes, there's no horizontal bar but it's still happening in Firefox. It seems to be browser issue then. I already cleared the cookies, cache and history though.